# SOAP can be sent can't sent over SMTP, FTP why?

Tags: soap, ftp, smtp

SOAP uses HTTP for sending request to server, but can't used over SMTP, FTP why ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a SOAP message have to be sent over HTTP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540301/why-does-a-soap-message-have-to-be-sent-over-http)

Answer (score 0):

FTP and SMTP can be used to send SOAP messages, it is just most common to send it over HTTP, see other post on this matter: 
[Why does a SOAP message have to be sent over HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540301/why-does-a-soap-message-have-to-be-sent-over-http)